# How to tell if a method has been accessed by click in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

When there is a method that is accessed by a click on an element or on the initialisation of the page. How do you tell which way it has been accessed? I don't want to do stuff if the method is not accessed by click.

```
<tr class="row" data-bind="click: $parent.selectShippingMethod">
```

-

```
selectShippingMethod: function (shippingMethod) {

   var self = this;

        if (shippingMethod.method_code === 'localpickup'){
            //Do Stuff
            quote.shippingMethod(shippingMethod);
            instance.setShippingInformation();

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer, you can pass the event data in with the function, if its not clicked it will be undefined.

```
selectShippingMethod: function (shippingMethod, event)
```